# Causing a click event on a button on a form

Tags: javascript, html

[notesEntryForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVula.jpg)

Hi, in the form above, as long as the form has focus I can press the enter key and this will execute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#notesEntryForm').keyup(function(e){
      if(e.which == 13){
       alert('You pressed enter');
      }
   });
});
```

The problem is as soon as I click in either IFrame it won't. I know it's because the main form loses focus and it also references the form's ID, and the IFrame, that has another HTML page loaded, gets the focus. My question is, how can I get the main form to respond or listen for the keyup function when the focus is in the IFrame, specifically the one in the upper right as the other one is for display only but if it works for one it should work for both? I've tried using the IFrame ID but it didn't work. I think it's because the focus is actually on the page that's loaded into the IFrame. Is there a simple solution or would I have to add code to every page that gets loaded into the IFrame?

The reason I wan't to do this is because once you add values in the page in the IFrame the Add button becomes enabled and I'd like the user to be able to just press enter instead of having to click the Add button, which they have to do now.

This is my first question so if I've done it wrong I apologize. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try: 
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    ...
});

Comment: Yes I tried that. It didn't work.

Comment: Yes, it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

> would I have to add code to every page that gets loaded into the IFrame?

Yes.

Events do not bubble through a frame to the parent document.

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't going to be the case but suspected it might. If it is the case is the code similar to what I have already? I know I need to click the Add button on the main form, how would I do that from the page in the IFrame?